react-scripts build command uses outdated file content
I have a script that uses inquirer npm package to ask me to input a new version number.
After I input a new version number, my script edits my .env file's BUILD_PATH to match my new version number which webpack then uses to create my new build folder.
So if my last build path version was 1.0.1 then the output path would start out as
cwd/.env
BUILD_PATH=C:\Users\...\builds\1.0.1
and then my scripts would overwrite it to
cwd./.env
BUILD_PATH=C:\Users\...\builds\1.0.2
The problem is that the npm script react-scripts build will then use a cached version of that .env file and not the updated one, so in this case it would create a folder for the 1.0.1 version instead of the 1.0.2
I have tried:

await for five seconds after updating the .env file's content
Reading the folder structure after it's creation to update the cached memory
Accessing the .env file after it's creation to update it in memory
Deleting node_modules/.cached


You can try to remove node_modules entirely and/or copy the project to new location but there's no need for this. It's node_modules/.cache, not .cached. What you describe is not reproducible because all temp data that could affect this is expected to be in .cache. In case there was a typo when you removed it, that's it. Otherwise please provide a way to reproduce
